# OpenGL program won't execute properly if an explicit version is set

Tags: opengl, glfw

My computer runs Ubuntu 16.04 and is equipped with a Nvidia GeForce GT 630M graphics card with a proprietary driver installed. The `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` function shows that, by default, my graphics card supports OpenGL 4.5.

I have been following the [Learn OpenGL](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) tutorial series and I have the following difficulty: I can only get the tutorial's "Hello Triangle" program to run properly if I comment out the lines

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Leaving those lines as-is will prevent the triangle from appearing.

I am having trouble understanding why setting a required OpenGL version *lower* than the OpenGL version my card can support would make the program fail.

EDIT: the commands

```
std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Shading Language: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
```

output

```
Renderer: GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
Shading Language: 4.50 NVIDIA
```

if those lines are commented out, and

```
Renderer: GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 361.42
Shading Language: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

if those lines are left in place.

EDIT2: Here's the actual source code:

```
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

constexpr char FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE[] = "simple_fragment.shader";
constexpr char VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE[]   = "simple_vertex.shader";

constexpr int  WINDOW_WIDTH   = 800;
constexpr int  WINDOW_HEIGHT  = 800;
constexpr char WINDOW_TITLE[] = "Triangle";

constexpr std::array<GLfloat, 4> bgColour { 0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f, 1.0f };

/*
 * Instructs GLFW to close window if escape key is pressed.
 */
void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

int main() {
    // Start GLFW.
    if (not glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to start GLFW.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Set OpenGL version.
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create window and bind to current contex.
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_TITLE, nullptr,
                                          nullptr);
    if (not window) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to create GLFW window.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set keyboard callback functions.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    // Initialize GLEW with experimental features turned on.
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Failed to start GLEW.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create viewport coordinate system.
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, static_cast<GLsizei>(width), static_cast<GLsizei>(height));

    // Create a vertex shader object.
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    // Load the vertex shader source code.
    std::string vertexShaderSource;
    std::ifstream vsfs(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE);
    if (vsfs.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << vsfs.rdbuf();
        vertexShaderSource = ss.str();
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: File " << VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE << " could not be found.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attach the shader source code to the vertex shader object and compile.
    const char *vertexShaderSource_cstr = vertexShaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource_cstr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Check if compilation was successful.
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Vertex shader compilation failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a fragment shader object.
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Load the fragment shader source code.
    std::string fragmentShaderSource;
    std::ifstream fsfs(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE);
    if (fsfs.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << fsfs.rdbuf();
        fragmentShaderSource = ss.str();
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: File " << FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_FILE << " could not be found.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attach the shader source code to the fragment shader object and compile.
    const char *fragmentShaderSource_cstr = fragmentShaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource_cstr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Check if compilation was successful.
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Fragment shader compilation failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a shader program by linking the vertex and fragment shaders.
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);   

    // Check that shader program was successfully linked.
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (not success) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Shader program linking failed.\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Delete shader objects.
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // Coordinates of triangle vertices in Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC).
    std::array<GLfloat, 9> vertices {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f
    };

    // Create a vertex array object.
    GLuint vao;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a vertex buffer object.
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    // Pass vertex data into currently bound vertex buffer object.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create vertex attribute.
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Unbind the vertex array object and vertex buffer object.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glClearColor(bgColour[0], bgColour[1], bgColour[2], bgColour[3]);

    while (not glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Inform OpenGL to use the shader program created above.
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        // Bind the vertex array object.
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        // Draw the triangle.
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // Unbind the vertex array object.
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // Delete vertex array object.
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    // Delete vertex buffer object.
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    // Delete shader program.
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE and action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
}
```

Here are the contents of `simple_vertex.shader` and `simple_fragment.shader`:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

and

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I'll bet that the issue is not setting a lower version, but explicitly requesting a _core_ profile.

Comment: @derhass Unfortunately, only commenting out `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` did not change anything. Interestingly, GLFW will not even start if I *just* have that line, so perhaps there is some issue with the core profile.

Comment: @derhass I have added some extra information that may be helpful.

Comment: You have not provided the code which is actually failing. It is easy to make some mistakes, and it is also not too hard to make some mistakes which have the effect that something appears in a compatiblity profile, while it doesn't in core. Requesting a core profile _without_ requesting a GL version >= 3.2 is just toatlly invalid, as profiles has been introduced in GL 3.2

Comment: How do you draw the triangle? If it's done with `glBegin` and `glEnd` and friends then that will not work in core profile. Moreover the fact that NVIDIA uses its Cg compiler when with a 3.3 core profile seems strange to me. Are you sure your GLSL shaders are compiling when in 3.3 core mode?

Comment: @derhass I have now included the source code.

Comment: @rwols Yes, I found the use of the Cg compiler to be strange as well. However, I have explicit checks in my code to verify that the shaders are compiling. And I used `glDrawArrays` to create the actual triangle.

Comment: What happens when you explicitly ask for a core 4.5 context?

Comment: @rwols The triangle still does *not* appear. The shading language is 4.50 NVIDIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a typo in my code.

I used the function `glGenBuffers` instead of `glGenVertexArrays` to create my vertex array object. Apparently Nvidia accepts this, unless I specify an OpenGL version. I still find it puzzling but at least the problem is fixed.

Comment: There is a difference in that it's legal to generate your own ids for certain object types in the compatibility profile, while they need to be generated by the corresponding `glGen*()` calls in the core profile. This does not apply to VAOs, though. I suspect that the NVIDIA driver may not check for this correctly in the compatibility profile.